# when component complete render then change route in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a `WhatsNew` Component and this my route config:

```
@RouteConfig([

    { path: '/whatsnew', name: 'WhatsNew', component: WhatsNew },

])
```

I'm in the other route and component. My problem is that I want `whatsnew` to be completely rendered, then route change and navigate to `WhatsNew`. I don't want user see the rendering page, how to do it in angular 2?

Comment: Can you explain what's the purpose of this. To me this doesn't make sense. Why would you want to render something without being visible and then navigate away anyway?

Comment: yeess...i want send request to server and for example if true then route get into the change...

Comment: There is no need to render the component for that. Please add more code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What Angular2 version and what router are you using?

Comment: vRC1 and router-deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `CanActivate` lifecycle callback. This way you can either return a promise that completes to true when the call to the server returns that going to that route is fine or redirect to another route.

One problem is that `CanActivate` is a decorator and DI doesn't support decorators but you need to get a reference to your service to make the server call.

[This comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572) contains a link to a Plunker that demonstrates how DI can be used with `CanActivate`

There are a few issues that lifecycle callbacks don't wait for the promise to resolve before they continue the navigation. I don't remember if this applies to `CanActivate`. There is *again* a new router on its way and it is unlikely that issues will be fixed with the old routers.